# Excel macro creates more work sheets than is intended

Tags: excel, vba

I'm working on a piece of code that I use in multiple workbooks. The macro scans each row in a column, creates a new sheet for each unique value and copies all of the corresponding rows into said sheet. When I run the macro, it does its job but creates an extra 3 blank worksheets. If I run it again, it makes even more and I cant seem to locate the issue with it. 
I would also appreciate any other optimisations to my code. Dummy data is provided below
[data being separated](https://i.stack.imgur.com/woGEl.png)

```
   Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim LR As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim vcol, i As Integer
Dim icol As Long
Dim myarr As Variant
Dim title As String
Dim titlerow As Integer
vcol = 1
Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1")
LR = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, vcol).End(xlUp).Row
title = "A1:G1"
titlerow = ws.Range(title).Cells(1).Row
icol = ws.Columns.Count
ws.Cells(1, icol) = "Unique"
For i = 2 To LR
On Error Resume Next
If ws.Cells(i, vcol) <> "" And Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(ws.Cells(i, vcol), ws.Columns(icol), 0) = 0 Then
ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, icol).End(xlUp).Offset(1) = ws.Cells(i, vcol)
End If
Next
myarr = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(ws.Columns(icol).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants))
ws.Columns(icol).Clear
For i = 2 To UBound(myarr)
ws.Range(title).AutoFilter field:=vcol, Criteria1:=myarr(i) & ""
If Not Evaluate("=ISREF('" & myarr(i) & "'!A1)") Then
Sheets.Add(After:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)).Name = myarr(i) & ""
Else
Sheets(myarr(i) & "").Move After:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)
End If
ws.Range("A" & titlerow & ":A" & LR).EntireRow.Copy Sheets(myarr(i) & "").Range("A1")
Sheets(myarr(i) & "").Columns.AutoFit
Next
ws.AutoFilterMode = False
ws.Activate
End Sub
```

Comment: *I cant seem to locate the issue with i* - have you run the code step-by-step to debug and see what the behavior is versus what is expected? If you have not, please do that but remove `On Error Resume Next` first.

Comment: What happens when you try `For i = 2 To UBound(myarr) -1`

Comment: @ScottHoltzman i have and it does not produce any error. the code runs fine, it just has some kind of bug in it

Comment: @SiddharthRout it produces 2 extra sheets

Comment: @arron. *it does not product any error* - Remove `On Error Resume Next`. Also, step through **line-by-line** and look at expected behavoir versus what actually happens. The issue is not an actual error, but that your code is not behaving they way you expect. Testing each line as you go is the only way to figure out why. All that said .... Maybe try `For i = 2 to UBound(myarr) - 3`. Reason being that you are not starting your counter at 0 (where the array starts), but at 2, so you need to subtract 3 to equalize the loop, or account for the difference some other way.

Comment: Then in that case you need to revisit the line `myarr = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(ws.Columns(icol).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants))` and check what does the array actually has. No point subtracting 1 or 2 or 3 from `UBound(myarr)`

Comment: sorry, i didnt see that half of the comment. its giving me "application-defined or object-defined error" at  { If ws.Cells(i, vcol) <> "" And Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(ws.Cells(i, vcol), ws.Columns(icol), 0) = 0 Then }

Comment: @SiddharthRout what exactly do you mean. im still quite new to VBA so im not entirely sure what im doing

Comment: Did you not write this code? If you did then you should know why you have the line `Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(ws.Columns(icol).Spe‌​cialCells(xlCellType‌​Constants))` there and what it should accomplish :)

Comment: a significant amount of it was dictated to me by a friend who was trying to help me learn and i had just filled in what i could. he explained the code as we wrote it but i forgot most of it